# What's the full form of DTO

Tags: meaning

In my company, my colleagues always say 'DTO' when they take a leave. What is the full form of DTO?

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: [Take your pick.](http://www.acronymfinder.com/DTO.html)  I kind of like "Drug Trafficking Organization".

Comment: Can you provide more context? Are they leaving for an extended period of time or just when they're leaving every day from the office? If it's extended, thanks to @HotLicks' link, it's probably "discretionary time off."

Comment: Suggesting migration to [workplace.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTO is Discretionary Time Off. A similar expression is PTO or Paid Time Off.

[This article](http://jimromenesko.com/2014/11/14/tribune-publishing-implements-discretionary-time-off-policy/) at jimromensko.com describes DTO as implemented Tribune Publishing to be a performance based policy of giving time off at the discretion of management in a flexible way, and apparently without specified duration limits other than that the time off does not interfere with the employee's performance.

The differs from PTO, where an employee is given a fixed allowance of time off (with pay) and nothing more.